# Showing an SVG that I have as a string

Tags: svg, julia, jupyter-notebook

I have some code that outputs an SVG as string.

Eg

```
foo = """
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="200" style="fill: blue"/>
</svg>
"""
```

I would like to display it in the cell output as an image.
I've seen several libraries do this.
How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `display(mimetype, x)`

`display` has a form that takes a mime-type as the first argument.
IJulia uses this information to determine how to display that object

So the code to display your `foo`, is `display("image/svg+xml", foo)`
Which will draw a nice blue rectangle.

Answer (score -1):

In the newer versions of julia the accepted answer is no longer true. See [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/display-svg/57469/2) instead you must save the string to a file, then read it. Something like:

```
f = open("images/animage.svg", "r")
s = read(f) #Don't force Julia to read a "String"
close(f) #Don't forget to close your file!
@show typeof(s); flush(stdout) #FYI: So you can understand what type is read back
display(MIME("image/svg+xml"), s)
```

The above code was taken from [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/display-svg/57469/2)